# How to change only the last repeated value from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, optimization

Basically I want to change only the last key 'name' repeated value from 'Flag' key in which key1 and key2 are defined over two loops above.

What I'm trying to do is the following (but I can't find an efficient way to do that):

```
       for i in range(len(messages)):
           if messages[i]['name'] == data[key1]:
               messages[i]['Flag']=2
           elif messages[i]['name'] == data[key2]:
               messages[i]['Flag']=2
```

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve? What is the structure of messages and what is the desired output.

Comment: very unclear. What is `messages`, what is `data`? And it seems like you're doing it just fine... Are you trying to check if `name` exists as a value in `data`? Then just do: `if messages[i]['name'] in data.values()`

Comment: Yes and then I want to replace only the last repeated.

Comment: Still very unclear... what do you mean by last repeated?

Comment: There are a lot of repetitions so in the last one I want to change the key Flag

Comment: assign it to a value ... `x = messages[i]` when you exit the list that will be pointing at the last occurance ... i guess

Comment: Again, if you actually expecting to get answers here, you have to give some examples of your data and what you want to achieve with it. If I kinda understand what you want, just iterate from the end to get the last one: `for message in messages[::-1]: if message['name'] == ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code posted, i assume messages is a list of dicts.

```
key_list = [data[key1], data[key2]]
for msg in messages:
   if msg['name'] in key_kist:
      msg['Flag'] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to alter the last dict that fits the constraints then loop through it backwards and on the first occurrence then alter the dict and break out of the loop

```
for i in range(len(messages), 0, -1):
       if messages[i]['name'] in (data[key1], data[key2]):
           messages[i]['Flag'] = 2
           break
```